# How to set the font of a table to sans serif, but keep the standard font for the caption?

Tags: tables, captions, sans-serif

Currently I have a latex table on which I want the font type to be sans serif (I do this by placing `\sffamily` inside the table environment). The only problem with this is that it also changes the caption font type to sans serif, which I don't want (I want it to just have the standard font type). How to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your table's caption is above the actual table, following tpographic conventions, just use `\sffamily` after `\caption` and before `\begin{tabular}`. In case you want to place the caption below the table itself, enclose the `\sffamily` and the entire tabular in a set of `{}`.

If you use the `caption` package, the caption's font is not affected by `\sffamily` inside of `table`. There is also no need for a set of braces, then.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{caption text}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1& 2 \\
text & text 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
{\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1& 2 \\
text & text 
\end{tabular}}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```